# Unable to run 'chef-client' from 'workstation' by knife ssh

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

When I run `knife ssh "name:node1" "chef-client"`

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to admagnifico.magnifico.fvds.ru -- Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for [fe80::225:90ff:fe19:4b12]:22
```

And I can't find out why it so...
on node runs ufw with enabled 22, 443, 80

Comment: [Solution](http://serverfault.com/questions/346418/knife-ssh-doesnt-find-my-nodes) which try to connect the node by ip not by fqdn as a default

Comment: The reason is that knife, makes query by fqdn which in my case is internal, so to avoid this, need to add key -a ipaddress and a user name -x your_user_name on vds.

Answer (score 1):

The hostname `admagnifico.magnifico.fvds.ru` is resolving to an unreachable IP address. The firewall isn't involved. That hostname isn't resolvable from here so I'm guessing it's an internal DNS setup.

Comment: /etc/hosts has line `82.1*6.3*.2*0 admagnifico.magnifico.fvds.ru admagnifico` so if this ip is unreacheble, how i ssh to it?

Comment: That's not something I can answer, check that the IP in your hosts file is correct or talk to your networking team if you have one.

Comment: can you ping that hostname?

Comment: I already find out why it don't work. The reason is that knife, makes query by fqdn which in my case is internal, so to avoid this, need to add key `-a ipaddress` and a user name `-x your_user_name` on vds.